# Get sheetname while importing excel sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to get the sheetname after I imported it excel workbook.
Below I was able to get the file name and now I would like to get the sheetname from the excel files imported and place in cell    "C2"

```
 Sub GetSheets()
'Update Excel Junction.com
Path = "C:\Users\momo\Desktop\Miscellaneous Shipment Packing List\New folder\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")
Do While Filename <> ""
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Range("B2").Value = Filename
Next Sheet
Workbooks(Filename).Close
Filename = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply by adding two lines into your loop, you can add the sheetnames:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
k = 1
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
Cells(2, 2+k).Value = Sheet.Name
Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Range("B2").Value = Filename
k = k + 1
Next Sheet
```

In this example, if your workbooks have several sheets, the sheets will be added in the cells C D E F etc...

Comment: Is this correct that you want to add the names in the workbooks you open and close or do you want to put them in ThisWorkbook

Comment: Will test it now as well ~

I would like it to be on the same work book  if possible in cell C2
[Link] https://i.imgur.com/as5g0mS.png [/LINK] something like this

Comment: Yes that is already in the code I provided, but do you want the name in B2 to be in the workbook that you open and close or in Thisworkbook? (In which case the next workbookname would be in B3, the one after in B4 etc...)

Comment: It works however do you think you can tweak/make some adjustment to it?
[Link]https://i.imgur.com/ZJWSRYH.png if possible i would like to have each sheet name to be under place at their own respective sheet generated instead of being in the next cell ...

Sorry for taking so long to reply... took me awhile to understand your comment above sir >.<

Comment: I m not sure what you want, you just showed in your image what results from the code no? Do you mean the names should be in C2 then C3 then C4?

Comment: omg my bad that was the wrong image... sorry for taking so long to reply 

If you click the image please see the "Desire" [Link] https://i.imgur.com/GrMuiup.png

You would see what I would like to have .... 

Sorry i do not know how to put them into words ...

Comment: what is the xxxx? I don t understand why you have two images for current and two for desire?

Comment: xxxx is something which was there except i just wanna censored it.

Current is the current code you provided for me...
Desire is what I would like if possible...

As you can see in current the sheet name is like what you said above  "the sheets will be added in the cells C D E F etc..."

If possible I would like to see it at each new sheet generated at "c2" which is what desire is ...

Comment: Check the small adjustment. It should write in every sheet the names in B2 and C2

Comment: Ahhh I am having a hard time running it... 
With the latest coding it doesnt show any sheet name on C2 cell for each sheet imported from workbook

Comment: it might be my side after all but if possible can you try it on your side?

Comment: What does incrementing *k* have to do with anything?

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
option explicit

Sub GetSheets()

    dim wb1 as workbook, sh as worksheet
    dim filename as string, path as string

    set wb1 = thisworkbook

    Path = "C:\Users\momo\Desktop\Miscellaneous Shipment Packing List\New folder\"
    Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")

    Do While Filename <> ""
        with Workbooks.Open( Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True)
            For Each sh In .workSheets
                sh.Copy After:=wb1.workSheets(1)
                wb1.worksheets(1).cells(rows.count, "B").end(xlup).offset(1,0) =  Filename
                wb1.worksheets(1).cells(rows.count, "B").end(xlup).offset(0,1) =  sh.name
            Next sh
            .Close savechanges:=false
        end with
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop

End Sub
```

The rows.count doesn't require a parent because wb1 is either an xls or xlsx and you are opening xls's (unless you are opening more than 65K workbooks).

Comment: Sorry about the edits; I got a little lost in the comments.

Comment: nothings seems to appear o.O? 
Dont see my filename and sheet name in its respective sheet ><

Comment: wait i see it but it is in the page where i click my button

Comment: The code should work but it hasn't been fully tested. If you want me to create multiple xls workbooks with multiple worksheets and import them to a mono-worksheet xlsx then you may have to wait until tomorrow sometime. If you have an individual problem, please be specific about the issue (subject to what you can describe within a comment).